# How to require_once from different directories?

Tags: php, permissions, directory, require, require-once

I am trying to require my "library" files from php files in different folders, but it gives errors when trying to access them from a subfolder. For example I have such a directory:

```
+ home    
- file1.php

 ++ subfolder
  - file2.php

 ++ libraries
  - code_generator.php
  - database_library.php
```

**code_generator.php** also depends on the other library:

```
(LINE 25) require_once(realpath("./libraries/database_library.php"));
//this works fine when called from file1.php, but not from file2.php
```

I try to call code_generator from ./subfolder/**file2.php** like:

```
chmod("../libraries/codegenerator.php", 0777);  // for the error at the end of this question
require_once("../libraries/code_generator.php");
```

When I run file2.php, it yields 2 errors:

```
**Warning**: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\home\subfolder): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\libraries\code_generator.php on line 25

**Fatal error**: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\home\libraries\code_generator.php on line 25
```

*line 25 is `require_once(realpath("./libraries/database_library.php"));`

Comment: I guess that if you do not have permissions to open this file, neither you will have to chmod it.

Comment: @AD7six that's what I'm suspecting. the realpath() function returns correctly from file1.php, but it returns empty in file2.php. I guess I'm using that wrong. But what's the right way?

Comment: @fedorqui I noticed this in PHP manual for realpath() : 
"The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE."
So how will I get the "permissions"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The file does *not* exist.

The error message reads:

> **Warning**: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\home\subfolder): failed to open stream:

And:

> Failed opening required ''

Error messages never lie (well, almost never), therefore you *are* calling:

```
require_once('');
```

### Realpath returns false for missing files

Realpath will return false if you pass it a path to a file that doesn't exist:

```
$return = realpath('this/doesnt/exist.foo'); // $return is false
```

Therefore, the argument passed to realpath doesn't refer to a file, which is the reason the path doesn't work.

### Don't over use realpath

If you remove the use of realpath, you'll find that the error message is probably obvious. At a guess you're trying to include `C:\xampp\htdocs\home\subfolder\libraries\database_library.php` - because there is a missing `.` in this:

> line 25 is `require_once(realpath("./libraries/database_library.php"));`

If instead you just define a root path:

```
define('ROOT', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\home\\');
```

Then you can use this constant with absolute confidence that these sort of problems wont occur:

```
require_once(ROOT . "libraries/database_library.php");
```

And if you do get the path wrong, the error message will make it obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [PHP super global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get the full path to your server document root, eg. /var/www/website/public.

The code could look like this:

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libraries/database_library.php';`

This way you do not need to set the document root path manually; PHP will always pick it up for you and make it available in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in any PHP file that is within your server document root.