# require_once with subfolders

Tags: php, require-once

I have Folder Home with two subfolders like the following

```
+Home  
 +include  
   - membersite_config.php

+iDiscover  
   -index.php
```

in index.php I added the require_once script to access membersite_config.php

```
<?PHP

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/membersite_config.php');
?>
```

I get the following error :
Warning: require_once(./include/fg_membersite.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Home\include\membersite_config.php on line 2
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './include/fg_membersite.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Home\include\membersite_config.php on line 2

The error says No such file or directory  while the The path "D:\Home\include\membersite_config.php" is correct . When I move index.php to be under the root , the page works well.

I also tried to use the following code as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776386/how-to-require-once-from-different-directories)  but it gives the same error

```
<?PHP


define('ROOT', 'D:Home\\');
require_once(ROOT ."/include/membersite_config.php");
?>
```

Edit :

I too tried 
    require_once("../include/membersite_config.php");
And it gives the same error

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: Try require_once("../include/membersite_config.php");

Comment: @Ares yes, everything works well when I move index.php to the root.

Answer (score 5):

You must include like this

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/include/membersite_config.php');
```

Because DocumentRoot can be not set in httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you have a require in your `membersite_config.php` that does not work on line 2.

Comment: I can see that it doesn't work. It says failed to open stream: No such file or directory , while the directory do exists. That's why I am asking whats wrong in my code

Comment: Read what I typed. The error is not in the index.PHP.

Comment: index.php can't access membersite_config.php , when it's inside the subfolder iDiscover. When I move index.php to the root. the same code works with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/home/include/membersite_config.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require_once("../include/membersite_config.php");
```

**don't forget to check the file/folder permissions!**

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it gives the same error . The file folder permission is full control. And I can access the file when I move index.php to the root instead of putting it inside iDiscover folder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
require_once('../include/membersite_config.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it gives the same error

Comment: Are you placing the codes here?: iDiscover/index.php

Comment: yes . iDiscover is subfolder under the root (Home) folder

Comment: Please confirm the path: home/iDiscover/index.php or iDiscover/index.php

Comment: The physical path is home/iDiscover/index.php 
and membersite_config path is home/include/membersite_config.php

Answer (score 0):

'..' means back

require_once('../include/membersite_config.php');

means get out the folder you are in, then enter include...

if you have to get out three folders do this ../../../include... etc.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging try this:

```
<?php
$dir_files=glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/*');
print_r($dir_files);
?>
```

after you run this script, you will see if your filename(s) are correct.

Comment: I tried it and the file do exist

Comment: and i suppose is is spelled exactly like **membersite_config.php**?

Comment: If you run membersite_config.php, you get any error? (like Guido Jansen suggest)

Comment: membersite_config.php works. and the same code works well when I move indexx.php to the root folder instead of iDiscover folder

Comment: did you tried include()?